# Can I combine setting border style and multiple colors at the same time?

Tags: html, css

Can I combine these two lines into one? Also can someone tell me what does it mean when only three colors are set for the border color? Should it not be four?

```
            border: 1px solid;
            border-color: #bd362f #bd362f #802420;
```

Comment: you need border color, right? and gradient color or what?little bit more info plz..

Comment: Here is your answer for q2 mate: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-color.asp

Comment: if you want than you can set four colors but if you use three colors then the rest one color is set by default..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I combine these two lines into one?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border), the syntax would be:

```
border: <width> <style> <color>
```

So let's try this with multiple colors:

```css
div
{
    border: 5px solid #f00 #0f0 #00f;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Doesn't work for me.

> What does it mean when only three colors are set for the border color? Should it not be four?

Top, sides, bottom. Why don't you just try it?:

```css
div
{
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: #f00 #0f0 #00f;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all 4 sides are the same color, you can combine  them:

```
border: 1px solid #bd362f;
```

*Otherwise, not.*

It doesn't necessarily has to have 4 colors set. This interpretes:

```
border-color: #bd362f #bd362f #802420;
```

***to:***

```
border-color: #bd362f #bd362f #802420 #bd362f;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<style>
div{background-color:#09C;width:100px;height:100px;border-left:5px solid #06C;border-right:5px solid #0C3;border-bottom:5px solid #C69;
border-top:5px solid #FF0;}
</style>`

Try this. Hope you will be clear about that.